# Using vue 2 and vue 3 on the same machine

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm about to start first vue 3 project. I'm installing basic vue packages and have stucked installing vue-cli. Docs say: For Vue 3, you should use Vue CLI v4.5 available on npm as @vue/cli. To upgrade, you need to reinstall the latest version of @vue/cli globally.

Will global installation affect vue 2 project tooling? I would like to be able to keep vue 2 in some of the projects and use vue 3 in other ones. How this should be configured.

IT Man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install it globally using

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

and when you create a new project you could choose the version, your old projects built using vue 2 stay working with Vue cli 4.x.

Comment: How can I choose cli version when starting new project?

Comment: when you run `vue create your-project` it will ask you to choose the version and other tools like typescript and css preprocessors ..

Comment: I've many projects build using vue 2 and when I installed  vue cli 4 I've not changed any config and they continue to work.

Comment: I have used https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#vite to initialize new project. In this case there was no prompt.Any way thanks for help.

Comment: you're welcome, but vite doesn't work  with vue 2, I really recommend to keep using vue cli since it's more mature and stable

Comment: Do you know why vite is recommended in docs for vue 3?

Comment: it's suggested as one of the solutions to build vue app, I've worked with vue cli more than 2 years and it's awesome and the plugins based on it are stable, before some days I used vite to build this [starter template](https://github.com/boussadjra/vite-wind) and I needed a plugin to auto resolve components I found one but it doesn't work for me and I think you could face the same issue with other plugins

Comment: Ok, now i understand. Thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Vue CLI  does not affect your Vue 2 or 3 project tooling at all.  When run `vue create project-name`, you will have to select from the following options, (see [vue prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc1SW.png)).
Vue 2 or 3 version will be shown in your package.json file